# Помогите оценить сложность алгоритма

Tags: python, алгоритм, простые-числа

```
from math import log2, gcd

a = 2**30
b = 2**31
all_simple = []
all_log2 = []
all_paras = []
all_paras2 = []
final_paras = []
paras_counter = 0


def is_prime(num):
    if num == 1:
        return False
    for p in range(2, int(num**0.5)+1):
        if num % p == 0:
            return False
    return True


for i in range(a, b+1):
    if is_prime(i):
        all_simple.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O(n*sqrt (n))`, поскольку время вызова `is_prime(i)` осуществляется `(b-a)` раз, где `i` находится между `[a, b]` и работает во время `sqrt(i)`, если будем считать в общих случаях исключая все переменные, то это и будет худшим временем.

Реальное время намного ниже, поскольку оно пропускает много чисел за 1 или 2 операции, поэтому сложность в реальном времени составляет около `O (n + (количество простых чисел) * sqrt (n))`, вы можете исследовать эту тему, чтобы достичь строгой формулы.

Answer (score 2):

Формально алгоритм работает за константу, то есть за `O(1)`, ибо в нём зафиксированы параметры `a` и `b`, но будем считать их переменными.

Функция `is_prime()` являет собой простую проверку числа на простоту путём перебора делителей до `sqrt(num)`. Сложность `O(sqrt(num))` в худшем случае, то есть когда функции подаётся простое число.

Дальше идёт цикл, в котором перебираются числа от `a` до `b` включительно, простые из них закидываются в массив; `append()`, если не ошибаюсь, работает в среднем за `O(1)`. Сразу сделаем верхнюю оценку в виде `O((b - a) * sqrt(b))`. Но по факту алгоритм работает гораздо быстрее, так как полный перебор делителей до `sqrt(N)` будет осуществляться лишь для простых чисел, которых всё меньше и меньше при стремлении к бесконечности.

Обратимся к [статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) о распределении простых. Там говорится, что количество простых на отрезке [1; n] растёт примерно как `n / ln(n)`. Адаптировав для нашего случая, получим, что на отрезке от `a` до `b` будет примерно `b / ln(b) - a / ln(a)` простых, на которых будут перебираться все делители до корня. Получим примерную нижнюю оценку вида `O((b - a) + (b / ln(b) - a / ln(a)) * sqrt(a))`. Здесь мы не учли случаи, когда на простоту проверяется квадрат простого — на них `is_prime()` будет работать тоже достаточно долго.

Простите, я, наверное, довольно сумбурно написал. Дать точную оценку здесь весьма сложно из-за природы простых чисел.

Вообще получить список простых можно быстрее, применив [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) (если достаточно маленькие числа и хватает памяти, но это не случай автора вопроса) или алгоритмы проверки на простоту (приведенный в коде `is_prime()` проверяет через факторизацию) — Ферма, BPSW и множество других, но среди них много вероятностных и есть ломающиеся на особых числах — к примеру, тест Ферма не работает на [числах Кармайкла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0). На худой конец, есть [алгоритм Полларда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0), факторизующий за `O(N^1/4)`.